# From Json.NET to System.Text.Json, Replacing JsonObject(NamingStrategyType) Attribute

Tags: c#, json, json.net, system.text.json

I'm currently replacing Json.NET with System.Text.Json and am stuck at a detail.

The serialized data is used to query a web API. While most of the properties follow CamelCaseNamingPolicy, some of the classes follow SnakeCaseNamingPolicy. I have written a class to apply that policy (ok... copy/pasted from StackOverflow)

The problem is. In System.Text.Json, the NamingPolicy is set directly on the serializer. I haven't seen any equivalent for JsonObjectAttribute.

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class ApiFieldEditor
```

How can I handle the case where a class follows CamelCase, and a sub-property follows SnakeCase?

(my guess as to why they use both is that perhaps the SnakeCase come from older API code)

Comment: According to [Customize JSON names and values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#customize-json-names-and-values), the naming policy is being set for all properties, or you can customize it using `[JsonPropertyName]` attribute

Comment: So no other work-around that setting `[JsonPropertyName]` on every property of those classes? To help in this particular case, single-word property names won't need the attribute.

Comment: "I'm currently replacing Json.NET with System.Text.Json"  - a very bad idea.